# Ctrl + Pick Block Interferes with Default Key Binding

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, keyboard

I recently found out that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[pick block]</kbd> picks the block with tile data and this is very useful, except: my Pick Block is binded to `B` and I'd like to keep it that way. But <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> toggles Text to Speech.

**So, my question is, is there a way to make <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> + <kbd>**B**</kbd> *not* toggle Text to Speech?**

By the way, before someone says "look in controls" it is not listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [not currently possible with the game itself](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-122645).

That said, you can use an external utility, such as AutoHotkey, to remap button presses [while conditions are met](https://superuser.com/a/88239/222647) or with a [toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274170/1780502).