# How can I change normal Windows key bindings that use the Win key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, xbox-app, xbox-game-bar

On Windows 10, by default, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> opens the Xbox Game Bar. How do I switch it so that instead, it opens the Xbox App?

Comment: I'm not sure so I won't leave an answer but maybe look into [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377056/258509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have 2 links that explain how you can unbind and bind keys for your Xbox Game Bar and Xbox App:

- [Binding an app to a certain shortcut](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/create-keyboard-shortcuts-windows-10)
- [Removing the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahq8V05DU70)

In summary:

- In your searchbar, type in "Game bar shortcuts"
- Once in the settings, turn off "Record game clips, screenshots, and broadcast using Game bar"
  Now you have turned off your Game bar (You could also bind it to another keybind if you scroll down a bit in the Game bar shortcuts settings)

Now for the shortcut to the Xbox app:

- Create a desktop shortcut for the Xbox app
- Right-click the shortcut and click "properties"
- Go to the menu "Shortcut" and type in your shortcut key to open the Xbox app
- Click OK

Note: You probably won't be able to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, but other shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>[any key]</kbd> will work.